# Twitter api v2 subscription offerings

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2, twitter-api-v1

I have already Purchased the Twitter Basic Plan. But, the data is limited to only past week. I want full archive search access for my project, thus I want to upgrade my plan. In this [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/products/pro) of twitter apiv2, its saying pro account should give me access to full archive search. Whereas in this [documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/tweets/search/introduction), it’s showings that full archive is only available in enterprise access. Can anyone tell me if pro plan has historical data access? Also can anyone tell me how far can i access data historically with pro plan?

I tried contacting twitter support via forums and @Premium handle in twitter with no avail.